# Ка вывести товары привязанные к инфоблоку

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! 
У меня есть инфоблок - метки
У него есть поля "категории"(тип привязка к разделам) и "товары"(тип привязка к элементам)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

настройка url меток
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего добавляю метку, добавляю к ней категорию и товар. (путь метки /labels/testovaya-metka/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как вывести привязанные товары и товары из привязанной категории?

Товары выводятся в components/bitrix/catalog.section/catalog_block/template.php

Comment: В catalog.section в FILTER_NAME передайте массив ИД этих товаров. В чем проблема? В поле SECTION_ID компонента передайте ИД разделов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находите место где выводится информация о метке, там же добавляете вызов компонента `catalog.section`.

Перед вызовом этого компонента, то есть перед `IncludeComponent()` формируете свой фильтр:

```
global $myFilter;
$myFilter = ['ID' => $productIDsFromProperty];
```

В списке параметров компонента находите `"FILTER_NAME"` и туда передаете `"myFilter"`:

```
...
"FILTER_NAME" => "myFilter"
...
```